# Carouselview: If only one item in view, items is shown indefinatley

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

So a carouselview is awesome for showing multiple elements. But once ther eis only one element in the view and the element isnt as large as the whole screen is, the result is:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG2uF.png)

So I would need to make sure that if only one element is inside the view, it isnt repeated.

How can I set this or work around this issue without making two layouts and making only one visible, depending on how many items there are in the view?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13442

Comment: Thank you. I solved this issue as in my own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple. If the list contains only 1 item, just set the peek area to 0, otherwise to whatever value you wanT:

```
        if (contentOfListView.Count == 1)
            carousel_myAds.PeekAreaInsets = 0;
        else if (contentOfListView.Count == 2)
            carousel_mySales.PeekAreaInsets = Constants.PEEKAREINSETSHALF;
        else
            carousel_myAds.PeekAreaInsets = Constants.PEEKAREINSETS;
```